# audio.play() giving me "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException error"

Tags: javascript, audio

When I hit "Go Live" on VSCode, my audio files play and work fine.
But when I try to open it up myself I just get errors.

On Chrome I get: "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources."

On Firefox: "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The media resource indicated by the src attribute or assigned media provider object was not suitable."

What gives? I'm just using downloaded mp3 files on an audio tag, like this:

```
 <audio src="/audio/drum.mp3" id="drum"></audio>
```

Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting these errors and how to fix it?

Thanks